# How to clear the dropdownitems with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

Am working on asp.net mvc 3 razor engine, I have 2 dropdowns in a page when an item is selected in dropdown1 items loaded into dropdown 2, and there is clear button to clear all the values.Here the selected items are cleared but items loaded into dropdown 2 are not, how to clear all the loaded items in dropdown 2 ? below is the rendered html for dropdown2

```
<td>                       
Work description                     
</td>
<div class="t-widget t-dropdown t-header" style="width: 220px; ">
<div class="t-dropdown-wrap t-state-default"><span class="t-input">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="t-select"><span class="t-icon t-arrow-down">select</span></span></div>
<input id="WorkDescriptionId" name="ViewModel.WorkDescriptionId" style="display:none" type="text" value="" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.empty()` will clear all child elements within a parent.

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: in the source the parent class is same for dropdown1 and dropdown2,how can i clear only for dropdown2 just input id is different

Comment: Specify the ID as the parent. $("#Id").empty().. where Id is the id of dropdown2.

Comment: Class and ID are different, class can be repeated and ID's are unique.  If the ID of your dropdown is `dropdown2` then `$('#dropdown2').empty()` will empty it.

Comment: there is no id for the dropdowns..only this id is different                              <input id="WorkDescriptionId" name="ViewModel.WorkDescriptionId" style="display:none" type="text" value="" /></div>